# CSS animation reset with animation-delay

Tags: css, animation, next.js, sass, css-animations

I'm trying to animate some images on my landing page. I have an array of 10 images that scroll vertically to a specified point, and then the animation resets. This works fine, but my issue start when I want to add a dynamic animation to each image. On the first cycle it works fine, but after the reset of the animation, due to the animation delay, it also delays the reset. Is there any way to include the delay during the running of the animation, but as soon as it hits the end of the animation cycle, the elements all reset at once, then adhere to the delay again? I'm using next.js and scss, I've included my code below. You can find my example at [here](https://www.acquired.homes), and what I'm going for at [here](https://www.acquire.com). Thanks in advance!

Carousel.js:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from '@/styles/components/LandingCarousel.module.scss';

export default function LandingCarousel() {

    const images = [
        { src: '/NetworkingSkeleton.png', delay: 6 },
        { src: '/NetworkingSkeleton.png', delay: 7 },
        { src: '/NetworkingPreview.png', delay: 8 },
        { src: '/NetworkingSkeleton.png', delay: 9 },
        { src: '/NetworkingSkeleton.png', delay: 10 },
        { src: '/NetworkingSkeleton.png', delay: 11 },
        { src: '/NetworkingSkeleton.png', delay: 12 },
        { src: '/NetworkingPreview.png', delay: 13 },
        { src: '/NetworkingSkeleton.png', delay: 14 },
        { src: '/NetworkingSkeleton.png', delay: 15 },
    ];

    const listingImages = [
        { src: '/ListingSkeleton.png', delay: 6 },
        { src: '/ListingSkeleton.png', delay: 7 },
        { src: '/ListingPreview.png', delay: 8 },
        { src: '/ListingSkeleton.png', delay: 9 },
        { src: '/ListingSkeleton.png', delay: 10 },
        { src: '/ListingSkeleton.png', delay: 11 },
        { src: '/ListingPreview.png', delay: 12 },
        { src: '/ListingSkeleton.png', delay: 13 },
    ];

    return (
        <div className={styles.section}>
            <div className={styles.container}>
                {images.map((image, index) => (
                    <img
                        key={index}
                        src={image.src}
                        className={styles.animated_image}
                        style={{ '--delay': image.delay }}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className={styles.containerRight}>
                {listingImages.map((image, index) => (
                    <img
                        key={index}
                        src={image.src}
                        className={styles.animated_imageRight}
                        style={{ '--delay': image.delay }}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

LandingCarousel.module.scss:

```
.section {
    display: flex;
    height: 87vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;

    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: calc(400px * 5);

        .animated_image {
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
            max-height: 400px;
            object-fit: cover;
            animation: scroll 8s ease-in-out infinite;
            -webkit-animation: scroll 8s ease-in-out infinite;
            // animation-delay: calc(var(--delay) * 0.05s);
            // -webkit-animation-delay: calc(var(--delay) * 0.05s);
        }
    }

    .containerRight {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: calc(380px * 4);

        .animated_imageRight {
            display: flex;
            max-height: 380px;
            object-fit: cover;
            animation: scrollRight 8s ease-in-out infinite;
            -webkit-animation: scrollRight 8s ease-in-out infinite;
            // animation-delay: calc(var(--delay) * 0.05s);
            // -webkit-animation-delay: calc(var(--delay) * 0.05s);
        }
    }
}

@keyframes scroll {

    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-400px * 5);
        transform: translateY(-400px * 5);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-400px * 5);
        transform: translateY(-400px * 5);
    }
}

@keyframes scrollRight {

    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-380px * 4);
        transform: translateY(-380px * 4);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-380px * 4);
        transform: translateY(-380px * 4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can guess is to control animations with a little javascript and manage delays / repeat times with it, apply and remove some classes to parent elements and then use those classes to apply animations.

Comment: A basic example would be greatly appreciated.